# setting up teleport - Configure Domain Name and obtain TLS certificates using Let's Encrypt

Tags: server, remote-access, lets-encrypt, teleport

ok so what I want to do is set up teleport on a remote machine so i can access it over the internet. I am following the tutorial but I am no expert on any of this stuff. i try to copy paste the commands from here:

https://goteleport.com/teleport/docs/quickstart/

section 1c:

```
certbot certonly \
  --manual \
  --preferred-challenges=dns \
  --agree-tos \
  --manual-public-ip-logging-ok \
  --email foo@example.com \
  -d "teleport.example.com, *.teleport.example.com"
```

i changed the email and domain name, as it says in the tutorial, but the it asks me to :

```
Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.teleport.example.com with the following value:

XXXX
```

how am i supposed to change that? and where?

thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing `--preferred-challenges` certbot will ask you to confirm you own the domain by placing a TXT record. You can do that if you **own** the domain and you can access the configuration.

You want to create your own domain (check [Freenom](https://www.freenom.com/) to obtain one at no cost) which you have full control on and you can add the TXT record.

Here is a reference to [Create DNS records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-at-freenom?view=o365-worldwide) at Freenom for Microsoft